# Tools for using the Stepdown Rule with Javascript

Tags: javascript, code-structure

I'm interested in using the [Stepdown Rule](https://dzone.com/articles/the-stepdown-rule) with Javascript, i.e. structuring the code so that it is readable from top to bottom and placing lower-level functions below their last usage.

Are there any tools that auto-format my code and/or enforces this pattern with linting?

Comment: At least [eslint](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/) doesn't seem to provide a relevant rule. My guess it's up to you as a developer.

Comment: I noticed that eslint doesn't support this.
I'm hoping that there is some other tool that does.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything that did this for me.

So I created my own eslint plugin based on the `no-use-before-define` rule.

Here it is if anyone is interested.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-the-step-down-rule